# Getting “Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.Aspnethostingpermission, System, Version 2.0.0.0, ” in SSRS 2008

Tags: javascript, validation, ssrs-2008, custom-code

I’m getting the following error while developing a report in SSRS 2008 R2:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.Aspnethostingpermission,
>   System, Version 2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089’
>   failed

When I use the following piece of custom code:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("< script language='javascript' >alert('From date can’t be more than the To date');< /script >")
```

I have searched across various sites to fix this but no use. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

**Here is the complete custom code:**

```
Function CheckDateParameters(FromDate as Date, ToDate as Date) as Integer

If (FromDate > ToDate)  Then

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("< script language='javascript' >alert('From date can’t be more than the To date');< /script >") 

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("script language='javascript'alert('From date can’t be more than the To date');<\script>")
```

should be (there was missing brackets):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('From date can’t be more than the To date');<\script>")
```

**edit:**
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1131887

Comment: yes i know i missed those brackets wantedly becoz i was not able give those brackets wen raising the question...